# sudo apt-get update 'skipping acuire of confg file 'doesn't support architecture '1386'

Tags: updates, dpkg, update-manager, architecture

```
[sudo] password for *****: 
>
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu cosmic InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
```

I have unrecognized architecture which is along with i386, the 1386 is a typo but access is only to privileged users or superusers in the dir.

Help gaining access to the directory would be great.
Have try rm but there is not access to those files in var/lib/dpkg/ dir  and same goes for edit of the files there without superuser privilege.

---

Edit:

### I managed to rm arch but would like to retain it and adjust the contents to be sure i386 architecture has all relating dependencies.

Edit 2:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
1001 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.10,o=LP-PPA-system76-pop,a=cosmic,n=cosmic,l=Pop!_OS PPA,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ Packages
     release o=obs://build.opensuse.org/home:strycore/xUbuntu_18.04,n=xUbuntu_18.04,l=home:strycore,c=
     origin download.opensuse.org
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.10,o=LP-PPA-lutris-team-lutris,a=cosmic,n=cosmic,l=lutris,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.10,o=LP-PPA-graphics-drivers,a=cosmic,n=cosmic,l=Proprietary GPU Drivers,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release o=dl.winehq.org,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=winehq,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.winehq.org
 500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
     release o=dl.winehq.org,a=cosmic,n=cosmic,l=winehq,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.winehq.org
 500 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary cosmic/main all Packages
     release v=18.04,o=system76,a=cosmic,n=cosmic,l=System76,c=main,b=all
     origin apt.pop-os.org
 500 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary cosmic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=system76,a=cosmic,n=cosmic,l=System76,c=main,b=amd64
     origin apt.pop-os.org
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=18.10,o=Ubuntu,a=cosmic-backports,n=cosmic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=18.10,o=Ubuntu,a=cosmic-security,n=cosmic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=18.10,o=Ubuntu,a=cosmic-security,n=cosmic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=18.10,o=Ubuntu,a=cosmic-security,n=cosmic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.10,o=Ubuntu,a=cosmic-security,n=cosmic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=18.10,o=Ubuntu,a=cosmic-updates,n=cosmic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=18.10,o=Ubuntu,a=cosmic-updates,n=cosmic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=18.10,o=Ubuntu,a=cosmic-updates,n=cosmic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.10,o=Ubuntu,a=cosmic-updates,n=cosmic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=18.10,o=Ubuntu,a=cosmic,n=cosmic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=18.10,o=Ubuntu,a=cosmic,n=cosmic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=18.10,o=Ubuntu,a=cosmic,n=cosmic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.10,o=Ubuntu,a=cosmic,n=cosmic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
```

---

Edit 3:

When I attempt rm `soures.list`

```
rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ /etc/apt/sources.list
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-cosmic.list.save': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-cosmic.list': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list.save': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/system76-ubuntu-pop-cosmic.list.save': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list.save': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/system76-ubuntu-pop-cosmic.list': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list': Permission denied
```

---

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu: can you please add the output of `apt-cache policy` to your question?

Comment: Use the edit button below the question to modify your question: https://askubuntu.com/posts/1136294/edit

Comment: Plus in this instance it repeats [22 times] heading [1001 x1 times [500 x20 times] with other, amd64 Packages, to repositories of Pop!_OS v18.10, ppa.launchpad.net, origin, download.opensues.org, winehq.org,pop-os.org, and us.archive.ubuntu.com ending with ```Pinned packages:```

Comment: Do you know a place that files affected by rm cmd go to recover them from that dir?

Comment: When I try to remove the sources.list and open a terminal from the target dir I am told I have no permission to remove files folders or create in that dir.

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 1):

#### Clean-up apt repositories

From the amount of entries from `apt-cache policy` I would suggest to clean-up the registered repositories first and fix the issue. Try the following steps

1. Backup old apt repositories

   ```
   $ sudo cp -r /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ /etc/apt/sources.list.d_backup
   $ sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list_backup
   ```
2. Delete old and create new `sources.list` with default repositories

   ```
   $ rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ /etc/apt/sources.list
   $ for i in cosmic cosmic-updates cosmic-security cosmic-backports; do \
       echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $i main restricted universe multiverse" | \
       sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list; \
       done
   ```
3. Clean repository lists and run update again

   ```
   $ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
   $ sudo apt update
   ```
4. (optional) Clean packages

   It look like you have a lot of additional external repositories. Try to fix any problems that are coming from this repos.

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
   $ sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

   If that's not enough, remove the broken packages with `sudo dpkg -r <package name>`

#### Add missing apt repositories one-by-one

When `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` do not show any errors or actions, you can start the custom repositories from the backup files.

```
# e.g. from your repo list
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:system76/pop
$ sudo apt-get update
```